# Getting all possible combinations which obey certain condition with MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to constract an SQL query but I have no idea how to do it. If someone helps, I'll appriciate it very much.

I have the following table

```
GroupedBYField          ConditionField          ToBeSummeField
     1                        1                      1
     1                        1                      2
     1                        1                      3
     2                        2                     100
     2                        2                     200
     2                        2                     300
```

and I need to get all the possible combinations of `groupedBYField, SUM(ToBeSummeField)` which has
`SUM(conditionField) = 2`, that is the following table

```
GroupedBYField          SumField
     1                     3
     1                     4
     1                     5
     2                    100
     2                    200
     2                    300
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you please expand/clarify your example? Where does the 3, 4, 5 come from for the SumField in the results set?

Comment: I guess it's (1+2)=3, (1+3)=4, (2+3)=5, since lines 1&2, 1&3, 2&3 match the requirement of SUM(conditionField)=2.

Comment: first row is combination of 
1   1   1
and
1   1   2
second row is combination of
1   1   1
and 
1   1   3
third is
1   1   2
and
1   1   3.

Comment: When requesting a SUM of 3, should that result in (group=1, sum=6)?

Comment: yes, we consider a combination of any number of elements which have 
the same GroupedBYField

Comment: Can ConditionField ever be zero?

Comment: When you say ConditionField can be any number, can it also be negative?

Comment: Do you need this to work on a specific RDBMS platform?

Comment: Actually I'm constracting a C# + MSSQL application. I need this operation handles as fast as possible so I want to do it with MSSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this works. It should also work where ConditionField values of 0 appear.
It will run on SQL 2005/2008.

It uses a recursive CTE to deal with any number of potential rows adding to the required value

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(GroupedBYField INT
,ConditionField INT
,ToBeSummeField INT
)

INSERT @t
      SELECT 1,1,1
UNION SELECT 1,1,2
UNION SELECT 1,1,3
UNION SELECT 2,2,100
UNION SELECT 2,2,200
UNION SELECT 2,2,300


;WITH numCTE
AS
(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GroupedBYField
                                           ,ConditionField
                                           ,ToBeSummeField
                                 ) AS id
               ,*
        FROM @t               
)
,myCTE
AS
(
        SELECT id
               ,GroupedBYField
               ,ConditionField
               ,ToBeSummeField
               ,'|' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '|' AS LEVEL
        FROM numCTE

        UNION ALL

        SELECT t.id
               ,t.GroupedBYField
               ,m.ConditionField + t.ConditionField
               ,m.ToBeSummeField + t.ToBeSummeField
               ,m.LEVEL + '|' + CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR(11)) + '|' AS LEVEL
        FROM myCTE  AS m
        JOIN numCTE AS t
        ON   t.id             > m.id
        AND  t.GroupedBYField = m.GroupedBYField
        AND  m.LEVEL NOT LIKE '%|' + CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '|%'

)
SELECT GroupedBYField
       ,ToBeSummeField
FROM myCTE
WHERE ConditionField = 2 -- amend this value change the target sum
ORDER BY 1,2
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

EDIT - added maxrecursion 0 to permit this to work on any number of source rows

Comment: This appears to assume you will always have either one or two rows summed.  It is unclear if this is the case in the question.  (For instance, if there are two rows with ConditionField = 0, every result with the same GroupedBYField could potentially have either or both of those rows summed, if three or more rows are allowed to be summed.)

Comment: @Conspicuous - the query isn't limited to one or two rows - the recursive CTE will build all valid combinations.

Comment: I'm wondering, why the `CASE WHEN t.id > m.id` if the `JOIN` is `ON t.id > m.id`. All rows will have `t.id > m.id`, will they not?